# how to detect a change in an array of objects REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an array of objects in the redux storage, and I need to update a component depending on whether that array is modified (an object is removed or added)

Comment: When state is updated any component(s) using that state are automatically re-rendered.  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. As long as you do the array update in Redux correctly (either using the modern Redux Toolkit `createSlice` or doing an immutable update in legacy Redux) and retrieve the array using the `useSelector` hook, your component will automatically rerender once that array changes.